# ifelse() and conditionally pasting column names across a data frame

Tags: r

I've got a data frame (df) with nine categorical variables, the first one being called student and then the names of eight school subjects.

I'd like to create a new variable called overall, summing up what subjects the student studied (dfgoal).

The problem's that what I've got doesn't work. Also I'm not sure how to best skip the first column (student). Use a list of the variables I do want to use (the eight subjects)?

Any help would be much appreciated.

starting point (df):

```
     df <-
  data.frame(
    student = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    maths = c("y", "n", "n", "n", "n"),
    English = c("n", "y", "n", "n", "n"),
    geography = c("y", "n", "n", "n", "n"),
    history = c("n", "n", "n", "n", "n"),
    art = c("n", "n", "n", "n", "n"),
    Spanish = c("n", "n", "n", "n", "n"),
    physics = c("n", "n", "n", "n", "y"),
    chemistry = c("n", "n", "n", "n", "y"),
    stringsAsFactors = TRUE
  )
```

desired outcome (dfgoal):

```
 dfgoal <-
data.frame(
student = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
maths = c("y", "n", "n", "n", "n"),
English = c("n", "y", "n", "n", "n"),
geography = c("y", "n", "n", "n", "n"),
history = c("n", "n", "n", "n", "n"),
art = c("n", "n", "n", "n", "n"),
Spanish = c("n", "n", "n", "n", "n"),
physics = c("n", "n", "n", "n", "y"),
chemistry = c("n", "n", "n", "n", "y"),
overall = c("maths, geography,", "English", "n", "n", "physics,chemistry,"),
stringsAsFactors = TRUE )
```

current code:

```
sapply(df, function(x)
  df$overall <- ifelse(df$x == y, paste0(names(df$x), ","), "n"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a one-liner:

```
dfgoal <- cbind.data.frame(
    df,
    overall = apply(df, 1, function(x)
        paste(colnames(df[-1])[x[2:length(x)] == "y"], collapse = ", ")))
dfgoal;
#  student maths English geography history art Spanish physics chemistry
#1       1     y       n         y       n   n       n       n         n
#2       2     n       y         n       n   n       n       n         n
#3       3     n       n         n       n   n       n       n         n
#4       4     n       n         n       n   n       n       n         n
#5       5     n       n         n       n   n       n       y         y
#             overall
#1   maths, geography
#2            English
#3
#4
#5 physics, chemistry
```

If you also want to replace the empty strings with `"n"`, you can do

```
levels(dfgoal$overall)[levels(dfgoal$overall) == ""] <- "n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a few things wrong in the `sapply`. First in the `ifelse` it should be `"y"` not `y` because it is not a variable, second the `paste0` should be replace with `paste` and `collaps = ","`,third `sapply(df` won't work properly because `sapply` will run over the columns and not the rows as you want.

This is how i did it:

```
overall = sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) ifelse(length(colnames(df)[which(df[x,] == "y")])!=0,paste(colnames(df)[which(df[x,] == "y")], collapse = ","),"n"))
cbind(df,new_colum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

merge(df, 
      melt(df, "student")[value == "y"][, .(overall = paste(variable, collapse = ", ")), by = student],
      by = "student",
      all.x = TRUE)
#    student maths English geography history art Spanish physics chemistry            overall
# 1:       1     y       n         y       n   n       n       n         n   maths, geography
# 2:       2     n       y         n       n   n       n       n         n            English
# 3:       3     n       n         n       n   n       n       n         n                 NA
# 4:       4     n       n         n       n   n       n       n         n                 NA
# 5:       5     n       n         n       n   n       n       y         y physics, chemistry
```

Comment: A slightly different data.table approach: `df[melt(df, id.vars = "student")[value == "y", toString(variable), by = student], on = "student", overall := V1][]`

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

```
> overall <- apply(df, 1, function(r) paste0(names(r)[r == 'y'], collapse = ', '))
> dfgoal <- cbind(df, overall)
```

Let's try to derive it:

pick the first line to play with:

```
r <- df[2,]
r
  student maths English geography history art Spanish physics chemistry
    1     y       n         y      n      n     n         n     n
```

now let's first produce a list of boolean where TRUE will be assigned to the position where a *y* appears, and FALSE otherwise, this is trivial:

```
> r == 'y'
  student maths English geography history   art Spanish physics chemistry
   FALSE  TRUE   FALSE      TRUE   FALSE FALSE   FALSE   FALSE     FALSE
```

Now you should get the point: we will use the last as a subset argument to get the desired elements from the *names(r)* vector, which contains the actual names for each of the positions:

```
> names(r)[r == 'y']
[1] "maths"     "geography"
```

Now we just need to concat all these, and iterate over the entire dataframe:

```
> overall <- apply(df, 1, function(r) paste0(names(r)[r == 'y'], collapse = ', '))
> dfgoal <- cbind(df, overall)
```